# 'Bramble Bush' has a figurative meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Why might this introductory (denoted 0L by some law students) law book be entitled Bramble Bush [http://www.amazon.com/The-Bramble-Bush-Classic-Lectures/dp/0195368452](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195368452) ?

I'm regardful of the definition of [bramble](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bramble?q=bramble) as a verb and noun. Here, I guess that it means 'blackberry bush', but this doesn't comport with law literally. What did I miss or misconstrue?

Comment: I think this should be on ELL. Someone who reacts to a fairly obvious metaphor by saying "this does not comport with law literally" will get better answers on a site specifically for learners.

Comment: I suspect that the metaphor has less to do with the fruit-bearing than with the combination of tangled-ness and thorniness. Since this usage of *bramble* is so distinctively BrE, it is perhaps unlikely that there is any relation with the *brier patch* of Joel Chandler Harris's famous story (Ch. IV of *[Uncle Remus, His Songs and His Sayings](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2306))*.

Comment: @TimLymington You’re right. I was momentarily trying to figure out what raspberry compôtes (a trifling matter, to be sure :) have to do with legalese. However, after carefully sifting through the nearest glossary of Latin phrases used jurisprudentially, I could find none that included *Rubus* in them. This should be shuffled off to ELL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the introduction to the book, part of which amazon unfortunately removes in it's preview, it says the author references a Mother Goose nursery rhyme.  It says that in the rhyme a man falls into a bramble bush and scratches out his eyes.  But then he turns to the thorns again and scratches the eyes back into his head.  Similarly in Law School, students first lose their old eyes and stumble around for a bit before gaining new vision.

See [link.](http://books.google.it/books?id=rxqSEU7y6lkC&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=rhyme%20The%20Bramble%20Bush&source=bl&ots=Rgjo4pZQgz&sig=rqaEJWXniqKL_c56beUmQmoSeKo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=59fCU82FMMKK8QGJu4G4BA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=rhyme%20The%20Bramble%20Bush&f=false)

The rhyme itself:
***The Man in our Town***
There was a man in our town,
And he was wondrous wise,
 He jumped into a bramble bush,
     And scratched out both his eyes;
 But when he saw his eyes were out,
     With all his might and main,
 He jumped into another bush,
     And scratched 'em in again.

There may be more verses, but this was what I found.

Comment: I pasted the Mother Goose rhyme into Google, which returned a number of hits. None of the half-dozen or so that I clicked on revealed any additional verses. One probably should not expect more than one verse from a nihilistic nonsense rhyme anyway.

Comment: That's Edward Lear ('A man of Thessaly'), and yes, it's just one quatrain.